# Jquery: What's the difference between $(function() { and $(document).ready(function() {

Tags: jquery

Hi I'm new to jQuery and I would like to know the difference between:

```
$(function() { });
```

and

```
$(document).ready(function() { });
```

Thanks!!

Comment: None, one is a shortcut for the other.

Comment: Check ready DOC, $(handler) here your handler is an anonymous function. So, there is no difference...

Answer (score 2):

The first notation :

```
$(function(){ ... });
```

is short-hand for the second-choice :

```
$(document).ready(function(){ ... });
```

They will both do the exact same thing, however the first will just require slightly less code.

Answer (score 0):

no difference - just different notation

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: question was 'what is the difference'.

Comment: @Aris I agree. Though succinct, it does answer the question. That said, a reference to the documentation is always desirable.